# How to replace Schema «availability» string with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I am noob with structured data implementation and don't have any code knowledge. I have been looking for a week how to solve my problem with "availability" in Google structured data testing tool.

My stocks on the front have 3 possibilities :

- "Stock : 1234" (text + stock numbers)
- "Stock : Coming soon"
- "Stock : On demand"

[Google Results example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3tge.png)

But he problem is Goggle accept only in my case "InStock" or "OutOfStock"

I have a CSS variable element #PdtXQStock named in a variable "Product-stock"

How can have :

if "availability" string contain numbers (not is number) ==> output "InStock"

if "availability" string is "Stock : Coming soon" ==> output "OutOfStock"

if "availability" string is "Stock : On demand" ==> output "InStock"

What is the proper Custom Js function from beginning to end?

```
function(){
var string = {{Product-stock}};
string = "https://schema.org/InStock";
string = string.replace(/Stock : Coming Soon/g, "OutOfStock");
string = string.replace(/Stock : On demand/g, "InStock");
return string.replace;
}
```

Comment: Deploying schema through GTM, however convenient, should not happen. There will be many issues with this in future. Deploy schema through your normal front-end. If you don't know how to deploy schema, you should either try and show us your attempts, or just delegate the work to a competent third-party. You're also needlessly inflating your question. Read on [mcve]

Comment: Unfortunatly I haven’t other choice except GTM because thé front is not in  my hands. Any idea  for a proper function ?

Comment: yes, share your attempts.

Comment: I just add the Google results image and my actual Script in GTM :-)

Comment: Any idea for a fully proper function ?

Comment: there are too many unknowns for anyone to give you a function. Either make a perfect description of what you need, or show your attempts.

Comment: I do my best to explain :-) is it more clear now ?

Comment: Write your code, debug it to your best ability. Then share it here with the actual problem you're facing. For now, your question is way too wide.

Comment: Just done but completly wrong :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: One week I search, research, and search again... none of my attempts worked :-( Need help...

Comment: I try to approach.... better?